# How can I express this sum in a easier way?

Tags: mathematics

For instance, I know that the sum of the first $101$ natural numbers can be expressed in the following easy computation:

$\sum_{i=1}^{101}i = \frac{101*102}{2}$

One of the questions is: and what about this sum?

$\sum_{i=1}^{101}i + \sum_{i=1}^{100}i + ... + \sum_{i=1}^{1}i = \sum_{i_1=1}^{101}\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}i_2$

And specially, what about the $nth$ case, i.e.;

$\sum_{i_1=1}^{101}\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots\sum_{i_n=1}^{i_{n-1}}i_n$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you plan to apply this to quantitative finance?

Comment: I am just extracting means and standard deviations of different portfolios. Suppose we have two assets: $X_1$ and $X_2$ and two ponderations $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ that must add up to one and each must be between 0 and 1. Then our portfolio is of coarse $\alpha_1 \cdot X_1 + \alpha_2 \cdot X_2$. If we allow the $\alpha's$ to increment by $.01$ then we have 101 possible different portfolios. WIth the same assumptions, but with three assets, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{101}i$ different portfolios. For the $n=4$ case we have  $\sum_{i=1}^{101}\sum_{j=1}^{i}j$ possible cases, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned, we have

$$\sum_{l=0}^{k}{p}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

You want to know

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\sum_{l=0}^{k}{p}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k}$$

you know that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k^2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Therefore
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\sum_{l=0}^{k}{p}}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}+\frac{n(n+1)}{4}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$

EDIT :

We can generalize it : 
For $m$ iterations,summing up to $k$, we have

$$Sum(m,k)=\frac{k(k+1)...(k+m)}{(m+1)!}$$

In other words,

$$Sum(m,k)={m+k \choose k-1}$$

$$Sum(m+1,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{m+k \choose k-1}}$$

Also,

$${m+1 +n \choose n-1}={m+n\choose n-2}+{m+n\choose n-1}$$
$${m+n\choose n-2}={m+n-1\choose n-3}+{m+n-1\choose n-2}$$
We keep doing this, until we get 
$$Sum(m+1,n)={m+1 +n \choose n-1}$$

Comment: I conjecture that the next one is $\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4!}$

Comment: Please prove it :D

Comment: Alex C is correct

Comment: @Canardini It worked for the first two terations ($m=2$), but just wondering, how did you come up with the answer? Did you prove it by induction?

Comment: With m=1 et m=2, we can clearly see a pattern. Yes it is proved by induction. If you believe that the post answers your question, please accept the answer